# Correct way to route with node js and socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Currently I have a node JS application that requires both realtime data and an archive of past data. I have a script running that sends the data through a socket.io to my front end interface. I grab all of my data from a mongodb database on the socket connect method but this is a waste since I only want some data on one page and other data on another page.

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
```

Should I be placing my socket connection inside this app.get function or is there another way? I want to make sure that I only grab that data I need from a mongoDB for the page that is being requested rather then getting all the data and parsing it on the front end.

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate as your question is very vague. How is everything interconnected? At what time do you need to call MongoDB, and what for? What are you sending (or intending to send) over the `socket.io` connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the url.parse function to get the name of the page like so:

```
var curURL = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
```

Then I can check the current URL

```
 if (curURL == '/') {
  //code
 }
```